# obfuscate angularJS itself in sync with app code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, obfuscation

Odd question, but, would it be possible to obfuscate angularJS script itself? I mean, change service names, directive names, everything that is standard.

Why?

I've used uglify and clusure-compiler, but my angular code is still "understandable": when I make an http-request, when a directive is declared, etc.

Instead of obfuscating my code, i'd like to include angularjs script into the process and obfuscate everything, so that even if someone knows angularjs, code will be much harder to understand.

Comment: In my experience `uglify` is pretty good at mangling identifiers; if you want to get farther there is the [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) `Advanced Mode`, but the code has to have some special properties to get it working and I doubt that you want to make that kind of changes to the Angular code. You could try to put all the code (including Angular) into one file and minify that, but I'm not sure whether this will effectively eliminate the "understandable" parts of angular. There is also [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) by Dean Edwards...

Comment: Will take a look at those. Thanks for now.

Comment: I have been testing JScrambler in my projects as part of their build process, one of which uses angularJS and the code seems kinda hard to read. Well it depends on the settings you use, but the result has been satisfactory for my team.